# Разбить слово по границе между разными типами символов

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть произвольная строка, но обязательно содержащая слово вида bla123blabla456 (количество разных групп и их порядок не фиксированы, могут быть разные комбинации). Есть срочная и очень важная задача - вставить пробелы на границах буквенного и цифрового символов. sed, awk, perl, python - замечательно. За подсказку регекспа, идеи или правильного направления гугления тоже буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой способ на `sed`:

```
sed -r -e 's/([a-z])([0-9])/\1 \2/gi' -e 's/([0-9])([a-z])/\1 \2/gi'
```

Answer (score 3):

В лоб, без особого интеллекта:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $s = "bla123blabla456\nbla123blabla456";
print "before:\n$s\n";
$s =~ s/([^\s\d])(\d)/$1 $2/gs;
$s =~ s/(\d)([^\s\d]])/$1 $2/gs;
print "after:\n$s\n";

$ ./1.pl
bla123blabla456
bla123blabla456
bla 123 blabla 456
bla 123 blabla 456
```

Comment: Тот же результат одним выражением с применением индийских методов программирования.  

    s/(?<=(?:(\d)|(\w))(?=(?(1)\w|^)(?(2)\d|^))/ /gs;
И без них:  

    s/(?:(?<=\d)(?=\w))|(?:(?<=\w)(?=\d))/ /gs;

Comment: Разбивает цифры, видимо, из-за \w.

Comment: Точно. Что то я загнался. Надо символьный класс указывать вроде [а-яa-z], а не \w

Comment: Да все мы тогось :-) ...глядя на код ниже от @Shamov :-)

Comment: Да, и кто-то еще говорит, что `perl` - не `write-only` язык :)

Comment: Да ладно, регекспы везде как инопланетный алфавит смотрятся :) А в остальном - это как писать, [вот так](http://www.ioccc.org/years.html) тоже можно :-)

Comment: @ReinRaus, хорошая регулярка, только внешняя скобка зачем?

    /(?<=[a-z])(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])/

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{ gsub(/[a-z]+|[0-9]+/, "& "); print }'
```

Comment: Этот способ портит остальные данные:

    $ echo 'word 42' | awk '{ gsub(/[a-z]+|[0-9]+/, "& "); print }'
    word  42